how to avoid lazy load when "Add Rule" is clicked on the table filters in primeng table
Currently, I'm trying to create a lazy table with filters in primeng table , now I have one question, is it possible to avoid firing the lazyload event when the user clicks on "Add Rule" since its causing unnecessary requests to the server . Is there a configuration I can change for this ?
i tried using the OnFilter on p-table.
onFilter(event: any) { event.preventDefault(); }
this didnt work for me.
